# Data not retrieved from database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this piece of code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wpex_programma';
// This retrieves the data from the database
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Anaam FROM {$table_name}" );
?>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?></td>
                <th>
                    <button name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    // Verify nonce and safe the data if the user is logged in.
    // Nonce docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/
    if (isset( $_POST['programma'] ) && isset( $_POST['set_programma'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['set_programma'], 'set_programma_action' )) {

      $data = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'programma', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
      $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if ( $current_user_id && ! empty( $data ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'programma', $data );
        }
    }
?>
```

The page does not return the data form the database. Nothing is shown except my navbar and footer. How can I solve this problem?

The code for retrieving the data and displaying it is:

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wpex_programma';
// Dit haalt de data op uit de database
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Anaam FROM {$table_name}" );
?>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?></td>
                <th>
                    <button name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

I will also show my database structure:

My wpex_usermeta, the choices have to be saved here:

[image]

My wpex_programma. All the programs are saved here:

[image]

EDIT

```
echo var_dump($wpdb->prefix);
```

yields

> string(5) "wpex_"

I also did echo `var_dump($tablename);` and it showed `NULL`

Comment: What's the value of $wpdb->prefix?

Comment: It is mandatory to use in Wordpress. It just adds the prefix to wpex_programma. It is in the variable $table_name which contains wpex_programma (the table I want to retrieve the data from). @LajosArpad

Comment: My question is: what's the value of $wpdb->prefix? If you do not answer the questions we ask, then it is difficult to help.

Comment: It does not have one @LajosArpad

Comment: Is it an empty string? Because in that case $table_name is wpex_programma. Is it null? Because in that case you have an undesired behavior. I need to know the exact value of $wpdb->prefix. You need to check that value by echo var_dump($wpdb->prefix); and let me know about the result.

Comment: I did the echo, the result is: ````string(5) "wpex_"````. @LajosArpad

Comment: If `$wpdb->prefix = 'wpex_'`, then what is the value of `$wpdb->prefix . 'wpex_programma'`?

Comment: I did ````echo var_dump($tablename);```` and it showed ````NULL````. So I took away the $wpdb->prefix and the data is retrieved. The buttons do look weird though. @DaanWilmer. And new data overwrites the previous data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the question and the comment sections, the information seems to be self-contradictory.

If

```
echo var_dump($wpdb->prefix);
```

yields

> string(5) "wpex_"

that means that due to

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wpex_programma';
```

`$table_name` will have the value of

> wpex_wpex_programma

which differs from the expected table name, which is

> wpex_programma

so, changing the code to

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'programma';
```

should solve the issue. Beware of code duplication, you are defining `$table_name` at different places, so you will need to apply the change everywhere.

You also claim that `$table_name` is `NULL`, which is either a printing before it was initialized, or, you have tested it at a place where it was not (properly) initialized at all. You will need to search for the pattern of

> $table_name =

in your whole source folder and make sure that it is properly initialized at all the occurrences.